# Handle exception raised in C++ thread in C#

Tags: c#, c++, exception, clr

I have a C# app that uses CLR to invoke functionality in a C++ code-base (which I cannot modify).

My C# app initialises the C++ stuff and then periodically interacts with it.

When the C++ stuff initialises it spawns a thread which then runs for the lifetime of the app.

There are certain conditions, beyond my control, which can cause the C++ stuff to raise an exception - this is crashing my app. I must emphasize that the cause of the crash is not initiated by anything my app does**.

I've tried AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException route, but it doesn't catch the exception.

Any ideas?

** Briefly, the C++ stuff fires up Direct3D - if the device is lost an exception is raised. Several things can cause this, but a good example is if the user locks their PC (Windows).

Comment: I'd be tempted to make a C++/CLI wrapper assembly that can do this sort of glue logic. Have that call the underlying C++ code, catch any unmanaged exceptions and either handle them or pass them on as managed exceptions.

Comment: If the C++ thread terminates due to an unhandled exception and no managed stack frame is on top of it it is a pure C++ problem. If you cannot interact with that thread in some way the default CRT action will be invoked which will terminate your app. Even if you could handle the error you would have then to deal with partially created C++ objects which if there are statics involved will leave you with no way to reinitialize things properly. If the library offers no way to handle such things by e.g. registering some error, retry handler you will need to restart anyway.

Comment: Thanks @AloisKraus - I don't mind handling the error since I can simply re-instantiate and initialise the CLR objects.

Comment: @grae22: But what about the C++ objects?. If you get an exception in your thread which type of error do you get?

Comment: @AloisKraus sorry I might be completely misunderstanding you... but I don't think it's an issue - there's essentially just one CLR object I instantiate and interact with. If something goes wrong, it's not really a problem just to re-instantiate it and start again.

Answer (score -2):

You should execute external code in a different AppDomain, so if external code fails, your application will keep running despite the other domain terminates.

```
public static class NewAppDomain
{
    public static void Execute(Action action)
    {
        AppDomain domain = null;

        try
        {
            domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New App Domain: " + Guid.NewGuid());

            var domainDelegate = (AppDomainDelegate)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                typeof(AppDomainDelegate).Assembly.FullName,
                typeof(AppDomainDelegate).FullName);

            domainDelegate.Execute(action);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (domain != null)
                AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }
    }

    private class AppDomainDelegate : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Execute(Action action)
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can execute external code in the new AppDomain using this class

```
NewAppDomain.Execute(() =>
{
    //Here call external code
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
});
```

More here: https://malvinly.com/2012/04/08/executing-code-in-a-new-application-domain/

Comment: Are you saying I should do my C++ initialisation calls in your "call external code" method? Would the resulting objects not be disposed of when that method exists?

Comment: @grae22 Using this approach, you can be sure that if there is a failure in the external call your app will keep running. You don't give much details about your app, so assuming you need to call an external function and return, this is the way to go. If you need to keep alive your external objects, then you'll need a slightly different approach, but definitively running it in a new AppDomain is the way to go to deal with failing external code that kills your application.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar, I'm playing with adapting your solution.

Comment: I would love to know the reason behind those negative votes. It would be nice if we could discuss that.

Comment: @Oscar: Appdomains are not a suitable way to guard against unmanaged exceptions. You can recover to a certain degree from managed failures but not from unmanaged code. If e.g. from Direct3d the user mode part of the NVidia driver fails you have no way with managed code or Appdomains to recover from that.